# EntityFramework enable-migrations ArgumentException

Tags: database, entity-framework, database-design, azure

I am a newby in the beautiful world of Microsoft Azure and made my first hello world website. The next step is to create a database (entityframework) but I get an exception while creating the database from PackageManagerConsole (PMC). I read a few posts on the web that explained that I need to add the startupprojectname to the PS command, but unfortunatelly that doesn't resolve my problem.

I have 2 projects in my solution.

- "partyonwebsite" which is the startup project and obviously my website :).
- "models" where I will design my models / entities.

In the "models" project I have the classes "User" and "UsersDb". UsersDb is the class that inherits from DbContext.

Now, when I execute the following line in PMC:

```
enable-migrations -StartUpProjectName "PartyOnWebsite" -ContextTypeName "Models.Users.UsersDb"
```

I receive the following (not very helpful) error:

```
System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
```

I've had a look at get-help enable-migrations and played around a bit but not a lot of luck.

Did anybody bump into the same problem? Or can you point me in the right direction to help me solve it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Bas

Comment: Try setting your startup project explicitly in Visual Studio (right click -> set as start up project) on the "models" project, then just run enable-migrations from the PMC, without all the fluff, what happens?

Comment: Same story, argumentexception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved. If you run into the same problem, make sure that EntityFramework is setup correctly for your seperate "Models" project.

- Open "Manage NuGet packages for solution" in solution explorer (right click solution in solution explorer)
- Select "Installed packages"
- Select "EntityFramework" and click "Manage"
- Check your "Models" project (I checked both my website project and the "models" project)

Run your enable-migrations command again.

I also added a project reference from my Website project to the Models project, I don't know if that matters.

The command that successfully executed after my adjustments in NuGet:

```
enable-migrations -ProjectName Models -ContextTypeName Models.Users.UsersDb
```

Hope this answer helps another lost soldier in his path to get his first app running in Azure :).

Cheers,

Bas

Comment: Changing the drop down in the nu get console helped with the error but when i try to do the web project I'm still getting the error any advice?

when you "manage" what do you do?

Comment: @MoiHawk hey sorry this has been too long ago for me :). Never used it since, so best to ask a new question if you haven't already